# How to deploy a react app using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, create-react-app, deploying

I am new to **react.js** and trying to convert my websites content into react components as a way to learn it with friends. I am using `npx create-react-app` and want to put the app online with **Google Firebase**. The deploying was successful - but I could not see the localhost page with the components I am seeing when I run `npm start`. Instead there is an empty page.

I followed some online guides and run `npm run build`.

Than, I tried to add `"homepage:"` to **package.json** and set it as `"mydomain.com"` or `"."`.

I have also changed my **Firebase** public directory to the *build* folder (instead of *public*).

Nothing yet worked. does anyone has an idea why?

Comment: Have you looked at the official documentation? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#firebase

Comment: Thanks mate! This was one of the guides I followed, but turns out I did not fixed issue #2440: setting out "social worker" for first deployment. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to goto1 I looked again in react documentations and found out about issue #2440. Adding:

```
"headers": [
  {"source": "/service-worker.js", "headers": [{"key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache"}]}
]
```

in `firebase.json` solved it for me.

See more at: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#firebase